# Laptop stolen, are files on D drive protected?

Tags: windows, security, file-permissions

I got my laptop stolen. It run under w10 os. I did set user w/ password to log on my windows account. The drive came, from factory, a secondary drive partion called D in which I stored my documents.

If the guy that stole the laptop format C and install new OS, will he be freely able to access the files on D drive ?

Thanks

Comment: There goes a lot more into this question than you might think. It's best to assume that he is able to access those files. If you did have BitLocker enable he might be unable to do it. If not he might even be able to access your files on C by removing the drive from that laptop. It really depends on what security measures were in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No good news here I'm afraid. A passworded user account does not mean your files are encrypted, and I assume your laptop came with Windows 10 *Home Edition*, which does not feature Bitlocker encryption (that you would also have to actively turn on, even if it did).

Yes, if the thief fully formatted the HDD without looking, the partition would be wiped.
*However*, HDDs can simply be removed from the laptop and hooked up to another computer (USB enclosure or straight to SATA/M2/etc), at which point all files on that partition will be accessible.

Looks like Win10 Home does come with some sort of drive encryption btw, if your laptop hardware supports it (i.e. TPM): https://www.windowscentral.com/how-enable-device-encryption-windows-10-home
This might be useful for your replacement laptop. Do make sure you keep backups of your files on a separate drive (or cloud based storage) though!

Comment: Ok thanks. Crazy that such thing isn't covered by default. Anyway my fault first for not consider the risk first I hope he/she enjoy my booty pics. And if he out only hope u guys will enjoy it lol. Cya

Comment: @Waldon added a bit of additional information, assuming you want to encrypt your replacement laptop drive!

Comment: Well noted I will ensure to encrypt my future data. Thank MiG for the answer and the advise.

Comment: Of course! Do set up a separate backup btw, not just in case your laptop gets stolen or the drive dies, but also in case you lose your recovery key.